# Why can I not manually run more than one snapshot agent at a time

Tags: sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent, transactional-replication, snapshot-replication

My organization has a SQL Server 2016 instance with multiple databases, and multiple publications/subscriptions for each database, in a transactional replication set-up.

Occasionally, we need to manually run the snapshots. In the past, we have been able to run 4 or 5 snapshot agent jobs at a time without a problem, but recently we are not able to run more than one agent at a time.  When we try to launch a second agent job it stops immediately as a failure with the following generic message:

> The replication agent encountered a failure. See the previous job step history message or Replication Monitor for more information.  The step failed.

There is no other information in the previous step or in the replication monitor.

Is there any condition, e.g. environment or configuration, that would prevent running more than one agent at a time?

Comment: How are you firing off the snapshot, from the Replication Publication or directly on the Snapshot SQL Agent Job? Replication errors can be a little touchy to locate sometimes, but I'm sure the underlying error exists in the job step history or Replication Monitor as the error message you received suggests, try digging a little futher. You may more easily locate it if you keep the Replication Monitor open when you retry your use case, as you'll see the Monitor turn red on the specific Publication when it errors out, and then you should be able to drill into it futher via the UI of the Monitor.

Comment: Thanks for the response J.D.

Comment: Step ID: 1, Step Name: Snapshot Agent startup message., Message Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. The step succeeded.

Step ID: 2, Step Name: Run Agent, Message: The replication agent has been successfully started. See the Replication Monitor for more information.

Step ID: 2, Step Name: Run Agent, Message: <blank>

Step ID: 2, Step Name: Run Agent, Message: The replication agent encountered a failure. See the previous job step history message or Replication Monitor for more information.  The step failed.

Comment: Step ID: 3, Step Name: Detect nonlogged agent shutdown, Message: Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. Agent shutdown. For more information, see the SQL Server Agent job history for job '<job name>'. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 20557)  Replication-Replication Snapshot Subsystem: agent <agent name> failed. The replication agent encountered a failure. See the previous job step history message or Replication Monitor for more information.  The step failed. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 14151).  The step failed

Comment: We have used Replication monitor and Job Activity monitor to launch the snapshot jobs.